# What does "in l for l in r.text.split("\n")" mean?

Tags: python

I see an example code which use request.post to download a website such as:

```
r = requests.post('https://xxxxxxxx)
```

then rearrange the content:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text.replace("=", "")), 
            header=["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")].index(True)-1)
```

I cannot understand

```
["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")].index(True)-1
```

means.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: `"Index" in l` is a boolean expression asking whether the string `"Index"` is in the object referenced by variable `l`.

Comment: `["Index" in l for l in ["line one", "line two", "Index", "line four"]]` is sort of what that "list comprehension" is doing. You're going to get a list of True's and False's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = ["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")].index(True) - 1
```

Is equivalent to:

```
i = [
    ("Index" in line)
    for line in r.text.split("\n")
].index(True) - 1
```

The above sets `i` to the **line number** (counting from 0) just **before** the first line containing the word "Index".

For example, if `text` was:

```
0 From: Jane.Doe@example.com
1 To: Jon.Doe@example.com
2 Subject: Foo bar
3 Index: abcd
4 Comment: Hello, World
5 ...
```

Then `i = 2`, since line 2 comes just before the line with "Index" in it.

Let's break it down in parts:

`r.text` is the text from the downloaded webpage:

```
'''0 From: Jane.Doe@example.com
1 To: Jon.Doe@example.com
2 Subject: Foo bar
3 Index: abcd
4 Comment: Hello, World
5 ...'''
```

`r.text.split("\n")` is the lines of text as a list of strings:

```
[
    '0 From: Jane.Doe@example.com',
    '1 To: Jon.Doe@example.com',
    '2 Subject: Foo bar',
    '3 Index: abcd',
    '4 Comment: Hello, World',
    '5 ...'
]
```

`"Index" in line` is `True` if the line has the word "Index" in it, and `False` otherwise. So, `["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")]` is a list of booleans indicating if each line contains the word "Index":

```
[False, False, False, True, False, False]
```

The `string.index(value)` pattern returns the first index (counting from 0) of a list containing `value`. So, `i = ["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")].index(True)` is the index of the first line containing the word "Index":

```
3
```

Finally, we subtract one to get the line before. So, `["Index" in l for l in r.text.split("\n")].index(True) - 1`:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
r = '''
'hello there'
'Index'
'dummy'
'''
print(r)
# the following line returns a list with 'True' or 'False'
print(["Index" in l for l in r.split("\n")])
# the following line will find out the index where 'True' is found
print(["Index" in l for l in r.split("\n")].index(True))
# the following line with reduce '-1' from the index where 'True' is found
print(["Index" in l for l in r.split("\n")].index(True) - 1)
```

Output:

```
"\n'hello there'\n'Index'\n'dummy'\n"
[False, False, True, False, False]
2
1
```

The line `["Index" in l for l in r.split("\n")]` is a list comprehension and its equivalent basic python code is as follows:

```
final_list = []
for l in r.split("\n"):
    final_list.append("Index" in l)
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: maybe show how the comprehension looks as a for loop `for l in r.split('\n'):` to illustrate how to understand comprehensions.